# Exact match in array (MongoDB)

Tags: arrays, mongodb

I have a collection in MongoDB that looks like this:

```
{
 "_id" : 1,
 "parent" : 1,
 "input" : [
     {
       "name" : "IAA1",
       "value" : "IAA1 Value3",
       "displayOrder" : 1
     },
     {
       "name" : "IAA2",
       "type" : "IAA2 Value4",
       "displayOrder" : 2
     }]
}

{
 "_id" : 2,
 "parent" : 1,
 "input" : [
    {
      "name" : "IAA1",
      "value" : "IAA1 Value3",
      "displayOrder" : 1
    },
    {
      "name" : "IAA2",
      "type" : "IAA2 Value4",
      "displayOrder" : 2
    },
    {
       "name" : "IAA3",
       "type" : "IAA2 Value4",
       "displayOrder" : 2
    } ]
}
```

What I need to do is, find only those documents that have all array elements that match the value of the `name`. For example:

1. `{"input.name":{$all:["IAA1","IAA2","IAA3"]}}`

This works fine and returns both documents, but this:

2. `{"input.name":{$all:["IAA1","IAA2"]}}`

Returns both documents as well. My requirements is that the 2nd query should only return the first document and not the second as it has an extra element with `name:"IAA3"`.

> The order of the elements in the array is not fixed
>   I need to generate the query dynamically based on parent Id and what columns should be present.

Comment: How can your documents have the same `_id` ?

Comment: My bad, I have updated the `_id` of the second doc.

Comment: `$all` is equivalent to `$and` so above query in `$and` as `{"$and":[{"input.name":"IAA1"},{"input.name":"IAA2"}]}` this match both documents because  `"IAA1","IAA2"` contains in both documents. To find exact macth you should use `aggregation` .

Answer (score 2):

You need to use combination of [$size](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/size/) and [$all](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/all/) operator to get desired result. **size must be the number of parameters that you are using in $all**. Here you must check size of input array to number of params in $all so that it will search given parameters ($all) only in those `input` array which size matches to number of params.

e.g. In sample Json you are using 2 params in $all so you must give $size of `input` as 2. In this case query will search only those `input` whose size is 2.

The query will be like -

```
db.collection.find({
"input.name": {
    $all: ["IAA1", "IAA2"]
},
"input": {
    $size: 2 // This is the number of param you pass in $all
}
}).pretty()
```

Comment: @Phoenix is it helpful to you??

Answer (score 0):

In order to have exact match, you should query just by the elements in the array. For eg:

```
{"input.name":["IAA1", "IAA2"]}
```

Refer [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/tutorial/query-documents/#exact-match-on-an-array)